# Import C++ classes in python?

Tags: c++, python

so.. let's say i have this C function:

```
PyObject* Foo(PyObject* pSelf, PyObject* pArgs)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Foo was called!", "Info", MB_OK);
    return PyInt_FromLong(0);
}
```

and then, I have to do this:

```
static PyMethodDef Methods[] = 
{
    {"Foo", Foo, METH_NOARGS, "Dummy function"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
Py_InitModule("bar", Methods);
```

and I execute my python script..
but C functions are a little annoying, it's C++ and I use classes for almost everything.

So, is there any way to import member functions from a class to my python script?

oh btw, the python script looks something like this:

```
import bar
from bar import *
Foo()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[boost.python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/) enables you to do that very effectively.

Answer (score 2):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) would work pretty well, too.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html) page. Search for 'free function'.

Answer (score 0):

Cython has the best [C++ wrapping](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) I have found, even though it is a bit more verbose than SWIG and it is a bit of a mindset to get into.  It's easier to write mappings than SWIG -- because it uses Python types -- but you have to write them all by hand.  It's also a very active project with a very friendly mailing list.  It also has good buffer support for NumPy.